# Center divs horizontally relative to each other with overflow without knowing width

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to center two `<div>`'s horizontally relative to each other.

Here is the basic setup:

css:

```
#outerdiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#reddiv {
    width: 1500px; 
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}
#bluediv {
    width: 100px; 
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="reddiv"></div>
    <div id="bluediv"></div>
</div>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/db545/)

So the `bluediv` should be centered under the `reddiv`.

Important:

- I do not know the width of the elements in advance. So just setting a `margin-left` or so will not work.
- And the `bluediv` should not be centered relative to the width of the page, but relative to the `reddiv`. So just setting `margin: 0 auto` to it does not work either.

Comment: Rather not, if unnecessary. Otherwise: Would that work with calculating the width using bounding box and setting a left margin?

Comment: Can't you add the blue div inside the dev div and position it outside using css..? otherwise i don't think it's possible using css. You might want to add js tag...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I do not get what you mean by "add the blue div inside the dev div and position it outside".

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gj6MR/

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately with this solution the `overlow: auto` on the `outerdiv` gets lost.

Comment: Yeps, i would do this in javascript and use the absolute positioning or margins. Really simple and short code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with adding another div, you can put bluediv and reddiv inside and use `margin: 0 auto;` to center bluediv to reddiv you get a great result. This works really well on all the major browsers I tested it on.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="innerdiv">
        <div id="reddiv">
        </div>
        <div id="bluediv">    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outerdiv {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#innerdiv{
    display: table;
}
#reddiv {
    width: 1500px; 
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}
#bluediv {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I set up a JSFiddle for you : http://jsfiddle.net/db545/11/.

Comment: bluediv is not centered under reddiv: it's centered in the Result window of JSFiddle (body) but there's far more red on the right than on the left of bluediv. EDIT: related to previous edit http://jsfiddle.net/db545/4/

Comment: I updated jsfiddle, that was the wrong solution, I had two jsfiddles open at the same time.

Comment: OK, that was rev 4. With this rev 7, on Firefox I see blue superimposed on red?

Comment: Is the additional `height: auto` in the `outerdiv` doing any job?

Comment: No, I just like to define both Width and Height.

Comment: Please set my answer as correct if it was the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I needed an extra div around blue and red div to center them:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/db545/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="component">
    <div class="component-inner">
        <div class="component-large">
            This text right is centered<br>nd also aligned with its sibling content
        </div>
        <div class="component-centered">This text is also centered</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.component {
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.component-inner {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.component-large {
    width: 1500px;
    min-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.component-centered {
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
```